# How to query a blob?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, blob

I want to create SQL query that returns some values and one of those values is **blob**.

When I just put blob column in my select it returns BigDecimal :|

its plain JDBC query with parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the javadocs section on [Materializing Blob Data](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/blob.html).

You need to call `getBlob` on the blob column and then read the binary stream.

```
    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("BLOB_COLUMN_NAME");        
    InputStream blobStream = blob.getBinaryStream();

    //e.g. save blob to a file
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int n = 0;  
    while( (n = blobStream.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    blobStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Inserting..

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE(fileName, "
            + "blobData) VALUES(?, ?)");
        stmt.setString(1, "somefilename");
        stmt.setObject(2, data);//data is byte[]
        stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Selecting..

```
ResultSet rs;

    stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT blobData "
        + "FROM BlobTest " + "WHERE fileName = ?");

    stmt.setString(1, "somevalue");
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    if (!rs.next()) {
      System.out.println("No such file stored.");
    } else {
      Blob b = rs.getBlob(1);
      BufferedOutputStream os;
```

- [Refer more](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/BlobJDBCdealswithBinaryData.htm)

Comment: actually setBytes() (instead of setObject()) might be more portable. But that depends heavily on the JDBC driver

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the method getBytes() from the ResultSet:

```
stmt = dbConn.prepareStatement("SELECT ...");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
byte[] blob = rs.getBytes(1);
```

This should return your blob object as a byte array.